# Search algorithms for top databases

Tags: database, algorithm

What are the search algorithms used in major databases?

E.g.

- Redis
- Cassandra
- Hbase
- Couchdb
- others

I am mainly interested in the algorithm that is used for "longest prefix match" in databases.

**Update:** I'll summarize the answers here.

Comment: At least IMO, this borders on both off-topic and not constructive. Knowing algorithms that would be effective for this in your code is one thing, but what does knowing what they used have to do with writing your own code?

Comment: @Jerry: Let's just say I am curious and yes you could consider this slightly off-topic although I am sure some folks would be happy to understand what to consider in their software projects.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it's used in databases, but have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie . You can build an index of your data and retrieve easily data using a prefix.

Comment: I'd like to have a mapping of [database:algorithm] and not particular algorithms.

Comment: Then, sorry for the noise :-)